# Regex Expression Differences

Tags: regex

I would like to understand the difference between the following 3 regular expressions:

I wanted to display all the lines in a file that consisted only of lowercase alphabets in them.

Here are the 3 regular expressions I tried:

```
cat filename.txt | grep ^[a-z]*
```

**Regex Description:** This will display all the lines starting with 0 or more lowercase letters. So, it will match either of the following:

```
zapato
113078
OLIVIA
```

Not exactly, what we wanted.

```
cat filename.txt | grep ^[a-z]*$
```

**Regex Description:** This will display all the lines starting with 0 or more lowercase letters till the end of the line. This matches the following:

```
fubuki
BALLIN
Kristine
```

This time there were no results with digits in them.

```
cat filename.txt | grep ^[a-z]*[a-z]$
```

**Regex Description:** This one works well for me. It searches for all the lines starting with 0 or more lowercase letters and it matches it till it finds another lowercase letter. For some reason, this works for me. However, I want to know how this is different from the previous regular expressions.

```
tonia
ecurby
totonno
```

Also, when the asterisk (*) in the regular expression means, 0 or more, then it should include all the results when I write, ^[a-z]*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short explanations of your regular expressions:

```
^[a-z]*
```

Match string starting with 0 or more characters from `[a-z]`.
Matches **empty** string and every string **starting with** character of set `[a-z]`.

---

```
^[a-z]*$
```

Match string containing nothing but 0 or more characters from `[a-z]`.
Matches **empty** string and every string containing **only** characters of set `[a-z]`.

---

```
^[a-z]*[a-z]$
```

Match string starting with 0 or more characters from `[a-z]` followed by exactly one last character from `[a-z]`.
Matches every **non-empty** string containing **only** characters of set `[a-z]`.

---

Use this instead of your current third option:

```
^[a-z]+$
```

It is semantically equivalent but simpler.

The expression `x*x` (or `xx*`) is equivalent to `x+` in regular expressions (with `x` being any expression). The latter is basically just syntactic sugar for either of the former more verbose expressions.

Or put differently: while `*` means **0 or more**, `+` means **1 or more**.

---

Comment: Thanks. But why does, ^[a-z]*$ match all upper case characters also. They do not belong to the character set, [a-z]?

Comment: Then your **matching** is somehow set to **case insensitive**. The **regex itself** is **case sensitive**. Check your settings/api.